# Is there a term for a child born after the death of its sibling?

Tags: expressions, phrase-requests

A couple loses their only child and some time later they have another child.  Is there a term for that second child? I once heard a parent use a phrase to describe it, but can't remember anymore.

Comment: This question is about opinions. Not facts.

Comment: @Lambie I'm sorry this is obviously a difficult / sensitive topic for you, but it's a valid question and has been answered in a clear and correct way (there is a term, but it's not widely known / used outside of a particular sub-community).

Comment: @Vicky I don't think you understand what I am saying. I'm saying that the naming is via others. I doubt a parent would say: "I had a rainbow baby". It is, as it were, third parties who say it.

Comment: Guys this is a perfectly straightforward language question. Please note everyone that on this site even **vulgar or incredibly offensive words** are regularly discussed, not to mention sensitive topics !!!

Comment: Good Lord!  This question itself is getting close votes!

Comment: @Fattie It is not that it is a sensitive issue per se. And it's not about vulgarity or offensiveness, either.  I would never say: I was a sunshine baby. Why don't you get that this is about what others call "us"?

Comment: @Lambie You're absolutely right that others shouldn't presume to use a word to define someone, unless they've first checked it's ok with that person. The difficulty is when the person **is still a baby** and it's the *parents* who, in their complex mix of joy and remembered grief, look for a special, *validating* term that captures their (to them) unique situation. The decisions that parents make can often be experienced negatively by their child in adult life: given name, choice of school, religion, gender & sexuality assumptions, etc. ...

Comment: @Lambie ... Why not post an answer that captures your own experience? This could cover both the way your caregiver(s) initially described you, and – if it's different – the relevant expression you prefer to use to describe yourself. While we expect answers to provide supporting evidence, I think a personal perspective from a specialist/minority community meets that requirement. And any links to additional information or "authoritative" perspectives would be a bonus. ...

Comment: ... We shouldn't prevent this question from being asked; instead, we should ensure that the answers provide a thorough *and nuanced* explanation that can guide all future visitors wanting to know how to approach the issue. :-)

Comment: @ChappoHasn'tForgottenMonica "Angel Baby," "Sunshine Baby," and "Rainbow Baby" are terms that refer to ***babies born just before another baby is lost*** due to a variety of reasons. They help immediate family members move through the grieving process and find meaning in the loss. https://www.webmd.com/baby/what-is-a-sunshine-baby#1 The OP asked about AFTER a baby is lost. So, all those 29 upvotes are mistaken, anyway.

Comment: @Lambie Are you saying that WebMD is more authoritative than any other source? Anyway, further down _that very same page_, it says: "A rainbow baby is a baby that you have **after the loss of a child**. They act as a symbol of renewal and hope. The rainbow stands as a symbol of excitement." (emphasis mine)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I believe **‘rainbow baby’** is what you're looking for.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_baby):

> A **rainbow baby** is a term for a child born to a family that has previously lost a child due to miscarriage, stillbirth or death during infancy

Also according to [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/rainbow_baby):

> A baby born subsequent to a miscarriage, stillbirth, or the death of an infant from natural causes.

#### Edit:

As @[Pam](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/283332/pam) pointed out in a comment below, [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=rainbow+baby&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Crainbow%20baby%3B%2Cc0) shows a spike in the usage of *rainbow baby* in recent years:

> [image: Google Ngram results for 'rainbow baby']

Comment: The opposite would be [**sunshine baby**](https://www.huffpost.com/entry/what-is-a-sunshine-baby_n_5a09ffbde4b0bc648a0d251c/amp).

Comment: @Centaurus Like gidds, I've never heard of this before either, nor seen it in print.  Doing a bit of searching, [this Yahoo article](https://www.yahoo.com/lifestyle/term-rainbow-baby-around-much-221512404.html) suggests it originated on issue-specific message boards in 2008.  It still is not a phrase which the overwhelming majority of English speakers anywhere in the world would know.  As gidds says, be prepared to explain it every time you use it.

Comment: @Graham, Expect to send them to english.stackexchange every time you use it.  ;-)

Comment: I'll go one step further than the folks suggesting this may not be widely understood, and also note that this is a jargon-y term that I wouldn't ever use to describe someone else's child or family unless I knew they used it themselves. Pregnancy loss is a profoundly complicated and variable experience that no two people experience the same way, and it could be perilously to presume to know how another person wants to identify or talk about their reproductive and/or family history.

Comment: this happens to be a key concept in the Mishnaic Tractate of Yevamot, but I don't think there's a generally accepted English translation... generally English translations of the Mishna leave it untranslated.... that's kind of a hint that there's no English term for it. The literal English translation of the Mishnaic Hebrew term would be "a brother that did not live in his world"

Comment: This is pop psychology or internet bullshit. I came next and there was no sunshine or any rainbows. Nothing like being named by the "other": The people who think they can come up with a term that makes the death of a child bearable.  It is not bearable. And if you come next, it can be awful. I know, I came next.  Ask yourselves: Who is doing the naming here? Huh?

Comment: Also watch out as 'rainbow' has associations that have nothing to do with deceased siblings.  Potentially, the inferred meaning by someone that doesn't know the expression could conceivably (pardon the pun) be taken offensively by the new parents.

Comment: I give you [Google ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=rainbow+baby&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Crainbow%20baby%3B%2Cc0) as testimony to the recent rise in popularity of this term. I've heard it comes from the [Dolly Parton quote](https://www.brainyquote.com/quotes/dolly_parton_126882): "...if you want the rainbow, you gotta put up with the rain". Most often, I've seen it used as a specific miscarriage-related term on baby boards and parenting forums (it's commonly understood there as a softer way to normalise miscarriage).

Comment: @Pam: Thanks. That's the most sensible comment here so far. All other commenters have been bickering about its rareness... just because they haven't heard it before, doesn't mean it's a rare and/or illicit phrase.

Comment: @DecapitatedSoul feel free to use that comment to strengthen your answer. I can see the other side, too: it's a bit of a cutesy term for a sensitive subject, and if you don't frequent baby forums (with all their associated acronyms!), then it's probably more than a bit obscure. But opinions on the internet-driven evolution of language aside, it is the right term right now.

Comment: There was an earlier, rarer, use of **C3 rainbow baby** OED **C3 rainbow baby**  n.  **(a) a child from an interracial, multicultural, or same-sex relationship;**  *1972   Her class has nicknamed Nathan ‘the rainbow baby’ because he is one-quarter each Navajo, Pima, Mexican and black.*  **(b) a baby born subsequent to a miscarriage, still-birth, or the death of an infant from natural causes (now the usual sense).** *2008  I have since gone on to have a healthy baby... She is my ‘rainbow baby’. Through the clouds and the rain she came and brought light and colour back into my life.*

Comment: An example of the use of 'rainbow baby': [Rainbow Baby - John O'Donnell on his Drama On One play](https://www.rte.ie/culture/2021/0402/1207601-rainbow-baby-john-odonnell-on-his-drama-on-one-play/). The first time I had come across the term, as it so happens. ([John O' Donnell](https://johnlodonnell.com/))

Comment: Purely for the record, I've only ever heard this in the first sense mentioned in the OED.  (Maybe because I'm so old!)  For example a few years ago in the UK there was a "coffee and cream" pair of twins born (as all the newspapers ahhed and gushed), one twin was more pale and one twin was more brown (from the mixed-race parents), the "rainbow babies" phrase was used liberally.  Anyway.

Comment: @Fattie: Language is changing (for example the word *nice* originally meant ignorant). I'd agree that
 you're so old.

Comment: @DecapitatedSoul   [Here](https://www.medscape.com/viewarticle/948391?src=WNL_infoc_210508_MSCPEDIT_Doc_Patient_Relationship&uac=30750PZ&impID=3357432&faf=1), a father refers to his baby girl as "rainbow baby". So it isn't a term a parent would never use.

Answer (score 18):

I have family experience of this and it was described as "second and only child."

It's often a difficult topic for the parents to discuss and the above statement is easy to understand.

Comment: Thank you for sharing that. It is equally difficult for the child, which in this case was me.

Comment: Thank you also for sharing.  100% agree it incredibly difficult for parents and the child., Thankfully its not common these days.   We talk about it matter of fact and openly with the 2nd child, but (try) to put no emotion or pressure on them as that's totally unfair.  It does create interesting situations, for example in the middle of the supermarket I was asked by the 2nd child (age 4) the question "why did _first baby_ die" just after we were discussing which cereal to buy. Keeps you on your toes.

Comment: Absolutely. You just have to say the truth.  Kids respond really well to truth, even when for a parent it can be hard to articulate. Anyway, lucky you to have a 4-year old. :) :)

Comment: @Lambie I was also born after the previous sister's death at birth. I never thought that I was meant to be a replacement --kudos to my parents for that-- but I agree with you that the simple facts, as far as the parents dare to share, are probably the best. Matlabgui, I'm sorry for your loss. +1 for "it's a difficult topic". Understatement of the week. In any personal context, great care should be exercised with any trite labels.

Comment: Having viewed your edit, I can see that you have coined this phrase. I'm sorry that you experienced this difficulty in your family, but self-coined phrases are not acceptable answers. Answers are supposed to be verifiable (i.e. you can point to an external source to confirm it).

Comment: @cjdennis to be 100% clear it was suggested to us by professionals, however I don't have a reference to link sorry.

Answer (score 10):

***[Replacement child:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Replacement_child)***

> A replacement child is a child conceived by parents to replace an older dead sibling.

(Wikipedia)

This term originated in the field of psychology. Outside of the field, it should be used with care, as the death of a child is an especially sensitive subject, and the expression can be interpreted as an extremely callous thing to say.

Answer (score 5):

In 1964  psychologists Albert C. Cain and Barbara S. Cain coined the expression:

***[Replacement child](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Replacement_child)*** to refer to a child conceived shortly after the parents have lost another child.

> In 1980, clinicians Robert Krell and Leslie Rabkin identified three types of replacement child: the "haunted" child, who lives in a family overwhelmed by guilt and silence, the "bound" child, who is incomparably precious and sometimes over-protected, and the "resurrected" child, who is treated as a reincarnation of the dead sibling.

(Wikipedia)

***[Google Books](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=replacement%20child%20&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Creplacement%20child%3B%2Cc0)*** shows that usage the expression “replacement  child” has increased consistently from the ‘60s especially in medical, academic and specialized papers.

But the expression can be found also in more popular online papers such as:

[www.theguardian.com](https://www.theguardian.com/lifeandstyle/2012/feb/18/replacement-child-sister-accident):

> ***I'm a replacement child*** -
> When Maria Lawson's older sister burned to death aged four, her mother was told by the family doctor to have another child. Which is how Maria came to be born, and – unbelievably – christened with the same name as her dead sibling

and

[www.huffpost.com](https://www.huffpost.com/entry/the-gift-of-being-a-replacement-child_b_9998168)

> ***The Gift of Being A 'Replacement' Child*** -
> I grew up believing that I was a replacement child, for I was given life after another child lost his: a brother my family loved and missed, and whose absence cast an obvious shadow over my grieving mother's heart.

Usage note by @Laurel

> “This term originated in the field of psychology. Outside of the field, it should be used with care, as the death of a child is an especially sensitive subject, and the expression can be interpreted as an extremely callous thing to say.”

Answer (score 0):

@Lambie  you are incorrect that it's what others say, because I myself am the proud mother of a sunshine baby, an angel baby as well as a rainbow baby and I say it about all 3 of my children. For the ones that don't know the meaning of these:

1. A sunshine baby is a child born before the loss of a child due to miscarriage, still birth or early infant death.
2. An angel baby is a child who gained their wings way too early, either still in the womb or in early infancy.
3. A rainbow baby is a child born after the loss of an angel baby.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: "Gained their wings"?